# Why are my TreeViewItems acting like RadioButtons?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF TreeView for which I've implemented a small model class behind the scenes. I bind a list of them to the TreeView's ItemsSource when creating the control. (I've pared the code here down a bit for the sake of simplicity, but it should be reproducable.)

```
public class TreeViewItemModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemModel> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public TreeViewItemModel()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemModel>();
        IsSelected = false;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemModel> MyTree { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add some dummy values
        List<TreeViewItemModel> items = new List<TreeViewItemModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    items.Add(new TreeViewItemModel() { Name = ("Node" + i)   });
        MyTree = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemModel>(items);

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

My TreeViewItems themselves contain checkboxes. Now, what I'd **like** to do is to bind IsSelected to the checkbox so that at the end of the day I (hopefully) have a list of TreeViewItemModel classes with IsSelected set to whether or not the checkbox is checked.

To that end, I have this style:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

and this TreeView declaration:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyTree}" >
    <TreeView.Resources>    
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type UI:TreeViewItemModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

This *almost* works. I can create a list of items programmatically and they get bound to the TreeView, check off items in my TreeView, and when I check them in C# IsSelected is set appropriately.

Except for one thing: my TreeViewItems all act like RadioButtons. I click one, and it sets IsSelected to true. I rejoice! But then I click on another... and it *deselects the first TreeViewItem*! I can never have more than one selected at a time.

But... why?! I don't understand at all. They're all bound to different items on the backend, so why would setting IsSelected change the state of another item?

:'(

Comment: Because you bind `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` to `IsSelected` in your view model which basically means that `CheckBox` is checked if `TreeViewItem` is selected

Comment: So it sounds like I misunderstood what IsSelected is for, and it only applies to one thing in the TreeView ever?

Comment: WPF `TreeView` does not support multi select. You can add multi select by changing `TreeViewItem` into `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton` (exactly what you're trying to achieve). Just remove `Style` for `TreeViewItem`

Comment: Thanks. That answered my question - if you want to submit an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I've added [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963101/why-are-my-treeviewitems-acting-like-radiobuttons/23964286#23964286) with some additional explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Style` for `TreeViewItem` you bind `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` to `IsSelected` property of your view model which basically means that `CheckBox` will be checked if `TreeViewItem` is selected. It happens so because WPF `TreeView` does not support multi selection.

You can easily add multi selection by changing `TreeViewItem` content into `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton`, exactly what you're trying to achieve, but then you cannot bind `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` to your view model. 
What currently happens is

- you click to select one item
- previous `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` is set to false
- this is passed to your view model by `IsSelected`
- which is then passed back to `CheckBox.IsChecked`
- new `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` is set to true
- and so on

Remove `Style` for `TreeViewItem` and leave only `CheckBox.IsChecked` to `IsSelected` binding

On a side note you don't need `StackPanel` when you want to show just one element like `CheckBox`

Answer (score 0):

You try removing your style? You should then see multiple selections